# Upgrade to Tridion 2013 SP1 from 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, 2013

We are plannning to upgrade from Tridion 2011 SP1 to Tridion 2013 SP1. In our implementation we are using TOM.Net for Templates and event system. Core services for custom pages and a simple GUI extn. According to deprecation guide, I couldn't see which all methods are getting deprecated in TOM.NET used for templates and event system code and core service methods as well. I need this to decide and plan migration strategy. Help me with any documentation which lists all the methods which are getting deprecated in TOM.Net,Core service API, GUI extn.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know - and I should know it :) - there are no deprecated methods in TOM.NET or CoreService. There are *additional* methods and features you can use, but there should be 100% backwards compatibility for both APIs.

Live Content has a page dedicated to "[Backwards Compatibility in Content Manager](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3E9B3513-6EBF-401E-A00D-618D4677F7CC)" which should help you understand what changed. The biggest difference for Core Service clients is that the endpoint for the new version of the API has changed, but the old version is still available. If you have CoreService applications you can either continue using them as is, or upgrade them to use the new endpoint URL (and associated client library).